# Double XML response from Stored Procedures

Tags: php, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, pdo

I am working on an Application and I am using Stored Procedures and PHP Laravel Framework. This is how I am handling the stored procedures in my code. The stored procedure I am using consists of a query result or results and an XML response. The problem is that I am receiving the XML response twice, see the example below.

This is my function in my controller:

```php
private static function execSP($sql, $parameters): ?array
    {
        $sqlQuery = "SET ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ANSI_WARNINGS, ANSI_PADDING ON; SET NOCOUNT ON; " . $sql;

        $conn = DB::connection(env("db_connection"));
        $pdo = $conn->getPdo()->prepare($sqlQuery);
        foreach ($parameters as $index => $paramValue) {
            $paramName = ":param$index";

            // Gebruik bindValue om de array direct aan de parameter toe te wijzen
            $pdo->bindValue($paramName, $paramValue);
        }//Execute
        $pdo->execute();
        $resultArray = array();
        try {
            do {
                $rows = $pdo->fetchAll();
                $resultArray[] = $rows;
            } while ($pdo->nextRowset());//check if the result was 1 or 0
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            // Vang en log eventuele databasefouten hier
            echo "Databasefout: " . $e->getMessage();

            // In geval van een fout, retourneer false
            return null;
        }

        $result = self::decodeXmlToArray($resultArray[count($resultArray) - 1][0]['result']);
        if ($result['Result'] === "1") {
            return [null, $result['Message']];
        }

        //pdo clean up
        $pdo->closeCursor();

        return $resultArray;
    }
```

And this is the output:

```
 0 => array:2 [▼
      "result" => "<Response><Result>0</Result><ResultDescription>Ok</ResultDescription><TotalRecordsQ1>11</TotalRecordsQ1><TotalRecordsQ2>50</TotalRecordsQ2></Response>"
      0 => "<Response><Result>0</Result><ResultDescription>Ok</ResultDescription><TotalRecordsQ1>11</TotalRecordsQ1><TotalRecordsQ2>50</TotalRecordsQ2></Response>"
    ]
```